# Am I being ARP Spoofed?

Tags: arp-spoofing

My ISP uses static IPs (IPv4) for providing an Ethernet connection. Now recently I have been witnessing a serious drop of speed sometimes. I called my ISP to verify if there were any problems in the network, which they always tell me if fine on their side. The ping to Google DNS is always fine ie. `ping 8.8.8.8 -t`

Now I think I am being spoofed because of two reasons. This is a local area broadband connection that I am using, ie. my neighbors are using the Ethernet from the same switch that is placed outside. even the IPs assigned are sequential. My IP is 172.16.130.196 my neighbors maybe 172.16.130.198 or something like that. So(correct me if I am wrong) you could do a scan of the IPs available in the network using something like AngryIPScanner.

The second reason why I think I am being ARP spoofed is because when I run the command arp -a in my Windows terminal I get multiple entries-: like so-:

> arp -a

```
Interface: 172.16.130.196 --- 0x4
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  172.16.130.193        00-25-90-ea-31-33     dynamic
  172.16.130.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
  239.255.67.250        01-00-5e-7f-43-fa     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
```

The only entry that I recognize in this list is `172.16.130.193` which is my default gateway. What the hell are the others ? Is it okay for there to be multiple entries in the ARP cache ?

**Am I a victim of ARP spoofing ? If so, how do I deal with it ie. can I ban the IP in my firewall or something ?**

If any more evidence is required please let me know.

Comment: Youre sharing a broadband connection (cable/dsl modem) with your neighbor?  Next time it slows to a crawl, ask them to stop using bittorrent.  Those other IPs are multicast (not real hosts) so they are not a symptom of ARP spoofing.

Comment: @JeffMeden Sharing means that the switch our Ethernet cables connected to is common.

Comment: i can recommend a tool which will give you confidence: `arpwatch`

Answer (score 6):

There is no indication of ARP spoofing, at least not in the information you have provided. What you should see in case of ARP spoofing is that your default gateway has the wrong MAC address, i.e. you would need to verify the MAC address in this entry:

```
172.16.130.193        00-25-90-ea-31-33     dynamic
```

Everything else are all perfectly valid entries:

```
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
239.255.67.250        01-00-5e-7f-43-fa     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
```

These are multicast addresses, not your neigbhors. From [Wikipedia Multicast Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address):

> IPv4 multicast addresses are defined by the leading address bits of 1110, ... The group includes the addresses from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255. Address assignments from within this range are specified in RFC 5771...

```
172.16.130.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

And this is the broadcast address of your network

Answer (score 2):

This looks perfectly fine. The addresses in your arp cache are for broadcast (172.16.130.255) and various multicast groups. This is normal.

When you are the victim of ARP-Cache poisoning there are no additional addresses in that table. But the MAC address of your router would typically not match the real MAC address of the router.

You can verify this by running wireshark and filter for arp packets. If you are spoofed there will be a high frequency of ARP Packets with spoofed information in it.

Comment: I don't have a router. So should that mean that I am safe ?

Comment: At some point you are using a router! You maybe don't own one but at least your ISP does so of cause you are in danger,...

Comment: Not necessarily. Many networks do not use routers at all, only switches.

Comment: @TylerDurden: a router is needed to access different networks (this is routing not switching), so usually you need a router to access the internet. In this case the default gateway 172.16.130.193 is the router, i.e. the one which knows how to send packets to other networks.